# CakePHP's login system

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, system

I'm trying to write an application in CakePHP. I ran into a problem with it's login system I need help with.

I set up a database table called users containing the fields id, username and password. Password is of type varchar and its length is 50.

My User.php model looks like this:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class User extends AppModel {

public $validate = array(

    'id' => array(
        'rule'      => 'blank',
        'on'        => 'create'
    ),

    'username' => array(
        'alphaNumeric' => array(
            'required'  => true,
            'rule'      => 'alphaNumeric',
            'message'   => 'Alleen letters en cijfers zijn toegestaan'
        ),
        'between' => array(
            'rule'      => array('between', 5, 20),
            'message'   => 'Gebruikersnaam moet tussen de 5 en 20 tekens zijn'
        ),
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule'      => 'notEmpty',
            'message'   => 'Dit veld mag niet leeg zijn'
        )
    ),

    'password' => array(
        'between' => array(
            'rule'      => array('between', 5, 50),
            'message'   => 'Wachtwoord moet tussen de 5 en 50 tekens zijn',
            'required'  => true
        ),
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule'      => 'notEmpty',
            'message'   => 'Dit veld mag niet leeg zijn'
        )
    )
);

public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (isset($this->data['User']['password'])) {
        $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);
    }
    return true;
}
}
?>
```

In my UsersController.php I have the login function like this:

```
//login function. Logs in a user
public function login() {
    //if already logged in
    if ($this->Session->check('Auth.user')) {
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }

    $user = $this->User->findById(2);

    debug($user);

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        debug($this->request->data['User']['password']);

        debug($this->request->data);

        debug(AuthComponent::password($this->request->data['User']['password']));

        debug($user['User']['password']);

        if ($user['User']['password'] == AuthComponent::password($this->request->data['User']['password'])) {
            echo 'user pw == hashed request data pw <br />';
        }

        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Gebruikersnaam of wachtwoord is onjuist.'));
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I've added a lot of debugging information. The check that checks if the password hashed is the same as the one in the database even works.

This is my Auth component in my AppController.php:

```
'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array('Form'),

        'loginAction' => array(
            'controller'    => 'Users',
            'action'        => 'login'
        ),

        'loginRedirect' => array(
            'controller'    => 'Users',
            'action'        => 'index'
        ),

        'logoutRedirect' => array(
            'controller'    => 'Users',
            'action'        => 'login'
        ),

        'authError' => 'U moet ingelogd zijn om deze pagina te bezoeken.'
    )
```

The problem is, that everything seems to be correct, yet it gives me the error message of incorrect username or password every time. I even tried not encrypting the password at all, but that didn't work either. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

P.S: I'm not really experienced with cakephp, so I'm sorry if I made an obvious mistake. I used the tutorial on the cakephp website.

**Edit:**
So I was changing some of the debug prints to use the method debug(), and I also deleted a certain part from the auth component, which had something to do with passwordhasher. I just tried to login again and now the login completely works. I guess that part is what was causing the problem to exist.

This is the code I had:
    'Form' => array(
                    'passwordHasher' => array(
                        'className' => 'Simple',
                        'hashType'  => 'sha256'
                    )
                )

I changed this to just 'Form' and now it works.

Comment: It would help if you shared some of the debug information. Like - is the debugged hashed password the same as in your database?  If not, that narrows it down A LOT.  Also - learn to use Cake's `debug()` - much nicer, and you only have to do it once instead of an echo for explanation and pr for data.

Comment: I edited my question because I fixed the problem.

Comment: upvoted for providing lots of code and also the fact that you were able to solve it yourself. way to go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, by using:

```
'authenticate' => array(
    'Form' => array
        'passwordHasher' => array( 
            'className' => 'Simple', 
            'hashType' => 'sha256' 
         )
     )
),
```

you were telling the `AuthComponent::login()` method to use the sha256 hashType when doing the password check in your login action.

However, in the `User::beforeSave()` callback, you were using the old AuthComponent::password() method to hash and store the password in the database. This method  does not accept a hashType parameter and defaults the hashType to sha1. If you do want to proceed with sha256 and the code above, change your `beforeSave()` method to use the new `SimplePasswordHasher` as shown [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#hashing-passwords). (I am assuming you are on Cake 2.4.x)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it better to use sha256 for encryption?

Comment: From what I've read, yes, [sha256 is better](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897434/password-security-sha1-sha256-or-sha512).

Comment: Alright, I will use sha256 then. Thanks for your input! :)